# Plotly python offline - visit url on click?

Tags: python, python-2.7, plotly

Is it possible to configure a [`plotly`](https://plot.ly/python) plot so that the user is taken to a specific url when they click on a certain data point?

My intended usage is for bar charts: I'd like to be able to click on a bar and then be taken to a url, each bar being configured with a different url.

I'm using plotly python offline to create a `<div>` which I'm embedding in a website.

Is this possible with the postMessage API on plotly python offline mode?

Comment: In Python... no.  But you can write Javascript to add `listen` events OR `hover` events that correspond to exact pixels on your barchart with a link inside in the postMessage API.  https://github.com/plotly/postMessage-API note you are going to have the easiest conversion if you DON'T go offline when tweaking your code (i.e. if you have sensitive data, just put in random data with `numpy.random.randn(100)` or something).  Once you have your barchart online, then add a .JSON to the link to get the info you need to use the postMessage API.  https://plot.ly/javascript/plotlyjs-function-reference/

Comment: Sorry ran out of space... http://codepen.io/plotly/pen/meaKwE you can change the JavaScript part to type: 'bar' then play around with the hover plot.ly/javascript/hover-events and put in the JavaScript the link you want to display. If I get an example made I'll post it here for your bounty :) You CAN then insert the JavaScript code via Python by doing something like I did here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36554705/adding-config-modes-to-plotly-py-offline-modebar

Comment: @Matt - amazing, thanks! Yes, please post an example and collect that bounty :)

Comment: @Matt - why would it be easier to start in online mode first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here I have created an example for you to edit here - right now it has the bars defined `Bar1` `Bar2` `Bar3` `Bar4` which indexes a URL for each in the JavaScript code (edit to your liking).  In order to use the PostMessage API the barchart you made has to be embedded in an iframe (see how to do it in the codepen link HTML section) and the JavaScript has to be included (on the right pane in the codepen link).

Full running example:
http://codepen.io/mslezak/pen/ZWxMBP

Plotly chart embedded:
https://plot.ly/~mslezak/11/y-vs-x/

Comment: Can I create/deploy iframes in offline mode?

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping and for producing an example. That's really handy and kind.

Comment: You can save the HTML out from codepen and add <!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"> to the start of the code, then add </html> to the end of it. Save out the codepen javascript as main.js and edit the link to it in the HTML file. Note you may have to do some more things to get it working this way.  You can likewise change the embedded iframe to point to your offline chart instead of a URL. Probably better ways of doing this but this should get you there.

Comment: Hi @Matt, If I generate Plotly chart in offline mode, it doesn't seem to work. Is that only works for Plotly embedded chart (e.g. embedded within http://plot.ly/xxx address?)

Comment: Hi @Matt: is there a way to generate it also (offline) in python? – Thanks